# I can not pass "git-credential-manager get" step when pulling, fetching, pushing, cloning with vscode ssh

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

My environment is that.

MyLaptop (Windows 10) <====> ServerPc (Windows 10) <====> github

When I connect ServerPc through remote control from my laptop, I can do full comment set of git.
But When I connect through ssh, pull/fetch/push/clone are not possible to perform. To more detail I did `set GIT_TRACE=1`, then found out that git process is pending on `run_command: git-credential-manager get` I tried to look for the solution for it, But I can not.

Is anybody who has a similar problem here?

---

**Updated**

I still don't know the root cause. But I found out that Microsoft already knows this issue and they suggest workaround like below at here(https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh).

> If you clone a Git repository using SSH and your SSH key has a passphrase, VS Code's pull and sync features may hang when running remotely. Either uses an SSH key without a passphrase, clone using HTTPS, or run git push from the command line to work around the issue.

So I'll close this question now. Thank you for your advice everybody.

---

**Updated**

I changed the method of auth from password to sshkey-without_passphrase. Then, I followed @bk2204's guide that described in below. That work for me perfectly. Thank you for your advice everybody.

Comment: Have a look at `git remote show origin` at your ServerPC without remote control. I guess it does not know the connection settings. See also `git config --list` under the same conditions.

Comment: @christoph There is no config problem on server pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that what's happening here is that you have an askpass helper set in the environment (via `GIT_ASKPASS`, `SSH_ASKPASS`, or `core.askpass`).  Since Windows graphics are not network transparent, when you log into the server PC via SSH, you're invoking a graphical process on the server PC that you can't interact with.  If this is the case, you'll need to unset those variables or settings when using SSH.

It could also be that you normally have saved credentials in the normal Windows credential store, but that isn't unlocked when you log in via SSH and the credential manager is hanging instead of handling it gracefully and prompting.  If so, you could see if your SSH server has an option to unlock the credentials, or ask the purveyor of your credential manager to fix the hang.

Comment: paragraph1: There is no graphical request on Git processing.

Comment: Okay.  Is one of those environment variables or config options set when you're using SSH?  You can check by running `env` for the environment variables and `git config -l` for the config options.

Comment: I added SSH_ASKPASS=1, GIT_ASKPASS=1. But Nothing to change. And I don't know how to change core.askpass. (core.askpass is not set now.)

Comment: None of them should be set in this case, and `1` is not a valid setting (they take a program name).  It looks like your problem is that the Git Credential Manager for WIndows is hanging, so you're probably trying to open a graphical window that isn't working.  Try doing something like `git -c credential.helper= push` instead of something like `git push`.